# NoSuchMethodException : com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.limit

Tags: apache-spark

I run spark to write data to hbase, but found NoSuchMethodException:

> 15/10/23 18:45:21 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, dn18-formal.i.nease.net): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.limit(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)Ljava/io/InputStream;

I found `guava.jar` in `hadoop/hbase` dir and the version is 12.0, but `com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.limit` is since 14.0, so `NoSuchMethodException` occurs.

I try to run spark-submmit by `- -jars`，but the same. and I try to add

```
        configuration.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/ljh")
        configuration.set("spark.driver.userClassPathFirst","true");
```

to my code, still the same.

How to solve this? How to remove the `guava.jar` in `hadoop/hbase` from class path? why it does not use the `guava.jar` in spark dir.

Here is my **code**:

```
  rdd.foreach({ res =>
        val configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();

        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", “ip.66");
        configuration.set("hbase.master", “ip:60000");
        configuration.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/ljh")
        configuration.set("spark.driver.userClassPathFirst","true");
        val hadmin = new HBaseAdmin(configuration);
        configuration.clear();
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/core-default.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/mapred-default.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/yarn-default.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/hdfs-default.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/hadoop/conf/hbase-default.xml")
        configuration.addResource("/home/ljhn1829/hbase-site.xml")
        val table = new HTable(configuration, "ljh_test2");
        var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(res.toKey()));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("basic"), Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes(res.totalCount + "\t" + res.positiveCount));
        table.put(put);
        table.flushCommits()
      })
```

and the **error** message:

> 15/10/23 19:06:42 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, gdc-dn126-formal.i.nease.net): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.limit(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)Ljava/io/InputStream;
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.nextBatchStream(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:420)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:392)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.spill(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:207)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.spill(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:63)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Spillable$class.maybeSpill(Spillable.scala:83)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.maybeSpill(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:63)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:129)
>         at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:60)
>         at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:46)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, gdc-dn166-formal.i.nease.net, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1277
>   bytes)
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on gdc-dn166-formal.i.nease.net:3838
>   (size: 3.2 KB, free: 1060.3 MB)
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on gdc-dn126-formal.i.nease.net: remote Rpc client disassociated
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@gdc-dn126-formal.i.nease.net:1656] has
>   failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is:
>   [Disassociated].
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks for 1 from TaskSet 1.0
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 1 (epoch 1)
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(1, gdc-dn126-formal.i.nease.net, 44635)
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 1 successfully in removeExecutor
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 0 is now unavailable on executor 1 (0/1, false)
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 1 to
>   gdc-dn166-formal.i.nease.net:28595
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 1 is 84 bytes
>         15/10/23 19:06:42 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, gdc-dn166-formal.i.nease.net): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=1, mapId=-1, reduceId=0, message=
>         org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 1
>         at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$1.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:389)
>         at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$1.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:386)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>         at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>         at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:385)
>         at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getServerStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:172)
>         at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$.fetch(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:42)
>         at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:40)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't set configuration inside the rdd.

Comment: if move out the rdd,  Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable

Answer (score 0):

add

```
      <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

because in https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#line.596

```
587  /**
588   * Wraps a {@link InputStream}, limiting the number of bytes which can be
589   * read.
590   *
591   * @param in the input stream to be wrapped
592   * @param limit the maximum number of bytes to be read
593   * @return a length-limited {@link InputStream}
594   * @since 14.0 (since 1.0 as com.google.common.io.LimitInputStream)
595   */
596  public static InputStream limit(InputStream in, long limit) {
597    return new LimitedInputStream(in, limit);
598  }
```